# replace a line containing pattern only in the first occurrence after another line that contains another pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace a line that contains the matching pattern `ForwardX11` in a file with sed, but only want to replace it when the line containing it is the first line found after another line that contains another pattern.

Example:

```
Host *
#    ForwardAgent no
#    ForwardX11 no
#    ForwardX11Trusted no
#    AnotherLine no

Host localhost
    ForwardX11 yes
```

In the example above I only want to replace the line `#    ForwardX11 no` with    `Forward yes` because this line is the first one after the line `Host *`. But I want to keep the line     `Forward yes` after the line `Host localhost` unchanged.

So far I tried using sed like this:

```
sed -i "/ForwardX11Trusted/! s/.*ForwardX11.*/    ForwardX11 yes/" /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

But it changes the second line too (ForwardX11 after Host localhost).

**EDIT 1**: It is supposed that I don't know if the line containing the pattern `ForwardX11` has `#` at beginning or not, and also I dont know if ForwardX11 is set to yes or no.

**EDIT 2**: It does not have to be done with sed.

Comment: `'s/#    ForwardX11 no/   Forward yes/'`

Comment: It is supposed that I don't know if the line containing the pattern 'ForwardX11' has # at beginning or not, and also I dont know if ForwardX11 is set to yes or no.

Answer (score 2):

Does it *have* to be sed? Easier (IMO) with awk

```sh
awk '
    $1 == "Host" {in_block = $2 == "*"}
    in_block && $2 == "ForwardX11" {print "    ForwardX11 yes"; next}
    1
' ssh_config
```

```
Host *
#    ForwardAgent no
    ForwardX11 yes
#    ForwardX11Trusted no
#    AnotherLine no

Host localhost
    ForwardX11 yes
```

Comment: No it does not have to be done with sed... Very good answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak '/^Host \*/,/ForwardX11/ s/#\?\(.*X11\) no/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Host *
#    ForwardAgent no
    ForwardX11 yes
#    ForwardX11Trusted no
#    AnotherLine no

Host localhost
    ForwardX11 yes
```